# Whats wrong with this javascript?

Tags: javascript

My assignment was to make a miles to javascript converter using a function, but it's not working. 
What did I do wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Script 3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        var miles = prompt("Enter distance in miles, or 0 to exit: ","0");
        if (miles == 0){
            alert("Thanks for visiting.");
        } else {

            alert(miles + " miles is equal to " + mi_to_km(miles) + " kilometers.");
        }
        function mi_to_km(miles){
            var km = parseInt(miles) * 1.60934;
            return km.ToFixed(2);
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know?  You didn't describe what your code is *supposed* to do.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: **Typo detected:** `toFixed(..)` `<-----` it was capitalized

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the call to 'Tofixed'. Try to put the 'T' to lowercase: 'toFixed'

Comment: As I see, somneone detected the issue before than me on the comments.